# php-fpm taking too much memory

Tags: php, php-fpm, memory-usage, memory-leak, alternative-php-cache

I am using Nginx+PHP-FPM with php 5.3.6 and it was working well for weeks.
A few days before I found out that most of the PHP-FPM children take 3MB but a few children are taking **700MB**. The web application is busy with 1000 requests/second. PHP-FPM is used with APC (opcode use)

Can anybody guide on this?

```
This script I used to get memory usage by child pid 
 http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py.

It could be verified by 'top' method too

top output(limited view)::
------------------------------
------------------------------
28419 daemon    20   0  844m 757m 4200 S    0  6.4   0:14.27 php-fpm                                                          

16788 daemon    20   0  700m 614m 4632 S    0  5.2   0:28.34 php-fpm                                                          

29450 daemon    20   0  669m 581m 3548 S    0  4.9   0:08.31 php-fpm                                                          

17881 daemon    20   0  642m 556m 4108 S    0  4.7   0:14.83 php-fpm                                                          

19048 daemon    20   0  642m 555m 4108 S    0  4.7   0:08.86 php-fpm 
11956 daemon    20   0 97612  10m 5476 S    4  0.1   0:39.57 php-fpm                                                          
11993 daemon    20   0 97560  10m 5188 S    4  0.1   0:39.18 php-fpm                                                          
11925 daemon    20   0 97328  10m 5144 D    3  0.1   0:38.68 php-fpm                                                          
11953 daemon    20   0 97748  10m 5172 S    4  0.1   0:38.51 php-fpm
```

php-fpm.conf:

```
/etc/php-fpm/php-fpm.conf
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
user = daemon
group = daemon

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 2000
pm.start_servers = 50
pm.min_spare_servers = 40
pm.max_spare_servers = 90
pm.max_requests = 10000
```

Following are the more debug inputs:

pmap::

```
pmap 28419
0000000000b52000     96K rw---    [ anon ]
0000000001a49000   1668K rw---    [ anon ]
0000000001bea000    208K rw---    [ anon ]
0000000001c1e000 770476K rw---    [ anon ]
```

strace::

```
strace -p 28419
Process 28419 attached - interrupt to quit
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>) = 0
recvfrom(4, 0x1bda1d0, 8196, 64, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 0 (Timeout)
recvfrom(4, 0x1bda1d0, 8196, 64, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000^C <unfinished ...>
```

PHP Modules loaded are::

```
[PHP Modules]
apc
Core
date
ereg
hash
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
memcached
mysql
mysqli
pcntl
pcre
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
xml
```

Comment: Is memory usage the same after restart service nginx and php-fpm  ??

Comment: No, the memory usage drops after restart but gradually it happens again for few php-fpm children.

Answer (score 1):

Try lowering the max requests to something like `pm.max_requests = 100`. This will restart the process after 100 requests, freeing memory that might have been lost due to memory leaks in your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `pm = dynamic` to `pm = ondemand`.
it will cut the Ram usage by half.